# How do I get the list of tags for a Spring LoadBalancer client connected to Consul?

Tags: spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I can get the metadata like this:

```
ServiceInstance serviceInstance = loadBalancerClient.choose(MY_SERVICE_NAME);

serviceInstance.getMetadata().forEach((key, value) -> log.info("Consul metadata entry - key: " + key + " value: " + value));
```

This unfortunately is not the tags - it return values like `secure` etc.

My question is: **How do I get the list of tags for a Spring LoadBalancer client connected to Consul?**

Comment: Cast to a `ConsulServiceInstance` https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/main/spring-cloud-consul-discovery/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/discovery/ConsulServiceInstance.java